# The eigenvalue or the two norm of a matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $M\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. And 
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
-\theta M-M+c_1 I^{n\times n}&
\theta M-c_2I^{n\times n}\\ 
I^{n\times n}&
0^{n\times n} 
\end{bmatrix};\quad c_1, c_2,\theta \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Note that, in general, $$\|A\|_2 = \lambda_{max}(\sqrt{A'A}) = \sqrt{\lambda_{max}(A'A)} \neq \lambda_{max}(A)$$ Also, how are you supposed to evaluate $M+c_1$ if $M$ is a matrix and $c_1$ is a scalar?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, thank you for your advice.

Comment: Are we given any information about $M$?  For example, is $M$ known to be normal or symmetric? It seems that my approach is not generally particularly helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we have
$$
B = \pmatrix{
-(1+\theta)M + c_1I & \theta M - c_2 I\\
I & 0
}
$$
It follows that
$$
B'B=\pmatrix{
(-(1+\theta)M + c_1I)'(-(1+\theta)M + c_1I)+I & (-(1+\theta)M + c_1I)'(\theta M - c_2I)\\
(-(1+\theta)M + c_1I)(\theta M - c_2I)' & (\theta M - c_2I)(\theta M - c_2I)'
}
$$
Perhaps expanding the entries will give you some insight into the nature of the eigenvalues of $B'B$.